# Modeling mongoose schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm in the process of creating my first web app using node with mongodb on the backend. I could use some opinions on the schemas/models I've set up.

I have three schemas: User, Pet, Food. Here's the general relationship of them:

Users have pets -> Pets have a list of ingredients and list of favorite foods -> Food has list of ingredients.

Here's my userSchema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 8,
    validate(value) {
      if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
        throw new Error('password contains password');
      }
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
        throw new Error('Email is invalid');
      }
    },
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});

userSchema.virtual('pets', {
  ref: 'Pet',
  localField: '_id', // associated with the _id of the user
  foreignField: 'owner', // the name of the field on the other object that creates the relationship, which we set to the owner
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Here's my pet model:

```
const Pet = mongoose.model('Pet', {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  badIngredients: [
    [
      {
        Ingredient: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  favoriteFoods: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Food' }],
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User', // reference to the User model
  },
});
```

and finally the food model:

```
const Food = mongoose.model('Food', {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  brand: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  flavor: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  ingredients: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
  ],
  imagePath: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
});
```

I'm unsure if it would be a good idea to have some kind of relationship between the pet's list of ingredients and the list of ingredients with the food. The general idea is a user can select ingredients that their pet is allergic to, and it will filter out the list of foods for them that DON'T contain those ingredients. They can then assign favorite foods to their pet.

I could also use some advice if using the `userSchema.virtual` property for pets is better than simply having a property on my user that is a list of pets.

The food itself will be static data stored somewhere.